# No module named 'PIL'. Среда разработки visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pillow

Такая ситуация. Решил попробовать библиотеку Pillow. Установил в нужной папке через powershell. Python3.8

`pip install pillow`

Далее хочу, допустим, сделать скриншот

```
import time

import cv2
import pyautogui as pg
import numpy as np
import PIL

screen = pg.screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Вылезает ошибка No module named 'PIL', кажется, что перепробовал уже все, причем остальные модули работают корректно, не могу понять в чем дело, может сможет кто дать дельный совет? Уже и удалял и устанавливал заново, и расположение папки менял...

Comment: Установка пакетов в виртуальном окружении. См. видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qa_MysBUPbI

Comment: Я уже ни во что не верил, но тут магическим образом все исправилось, правда я не понял как... видеогайд для visual studio, а у меня visual studio code, тем не менее я всю процедуру провел как в гайде, теперь у меня без ошибок работает во всех средах.